# How to implement Polylang functions in my theme's php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, polylang

I am translating a site with Polylang that was created by someone else using a custom theme. Some strings couldn't be found by Polylang, so I need to manually register them for Polylang to see. Now, some of the strings were pretty easy to translate using `__()`:

```
$args = shortcode_atts([
'link'      => 'service',
'text'      => __('Get the code now!'),
'title'     => __('Code'),
'id'        => '',
'class'     => 'width300',
], $args, '' );
```

But I don't know how to translate strings in these scenarios:

```
$popup = do_shortcode('[popup id="110" link="vacancy" class="" title="Code" text="Get the code now!!" ]');
```

Or here words Details, Close

```
$script = ' 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        btn = $(\'.add_vakan_info\'),
        popup = $(\'.add_popup\');

        btn.click(function(){
            var block_info  = $(this).closest(\'.vacancy\').find(\'.content\');
            if(block_info.hasClass(\'active\')){
                block_info.removeClass(\'active\');
                $(this).html(\'Details <i class="las la-angle-down"></i>\');
            }else{
                block_info.addClass(\'active\');
                $(this).html(\'Close <i class="las la-angle-up"></i>\');
            }
        })
        popup.click(function(){
            var text = $(this).closest(\'.vacancy\').find(\'.title\').text(),
                form = $(\'.vacancy_name\');
            form.val(text);
        })
        FileInput();
    })
</script>';
```

Or

```
else:
$html = '<h4>No vacancy </h4>';
```

Or

```
<div class="content col">
<div class="sp-20"></div>
<h4>Description</h4>
'.$description.'

<div class="sp-20"></div>
<h4>Requirements</h4>
'.$requirements.'

<div class="sp-20"></div>
<h4>Conditions</h4>
'.$conditions.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Polylang's [string translations API](https://polylang.pro/doc/strings-translation/).

#### Step 1. Registering your strings.

```php
// functions.php
add_action('init', function () {
    $strings = array(
        'no-vacancy'         => 'No vacancy',
        // Add more strings here...
    );

    foreach ($strings as $key => $string) {
        pll_register_string('theme-' . $key, $string, 'Hardcoded Theme Strings');
    }
});
```

Now these strings will appear in Languages > String translations menu, under the dropdown for `Hardcoded Theme Strings`

#### Step 2. Translate the Strings

```php
else:
$html = '<h4>' . pll_e( 'No vacancy' ) . '</h4>';
```

The value you enter on the back-end in the string translations menu will be used when translating this value.